# Bound functin using convex function

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, functions, convex-analysis

Given a continuous function $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$, I want to prove that there is a convex function $ g$ such that: 
1. $g(x) \ge f(x) , x\in [a,b]$
2. $g(a) = f(a)$
3. There is $p\in (a,b]$ such that $g(p) = f(p)$

Is it true?

Answer (score 0):

No, try $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ on $[0,1]$. Let us assume that a $g$ exists. Then, by convexity, $g$ lies below the line through $(0,f(0))$, $(p,f(p))$ on $[0,p]$. But this contradicts $g(x) \ge f(x)$ for $x \searrow 0$.

If $f'(a) < \infty$ (as a one sided limit), such a $g$ should exist. In this case, set $g_t(x) = f(a) + t \, (x-a)$. Then, for $t$ large enough, you have $g_t(x) \ge f(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ (note that this is not immediate, one has to proof it). Now, let $t_0$ be the infimum of all $t$, such that $g_t(x) \ge f(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Prove that $g_{t_0}$ has one additional touching point with $f$.

Comment: f isn't continuous on $[0,1]$, I asked only for continuous f

Comment: This $f$ is continuous in $[0,1]$. Why should it be discontinuous?

Comment: You are right, my bad. But still, I can't understand why the condition you wrote is enough

Comment: I have enhanced my answer.

Comment: Thanks. One last thing, why there exists infimum for $g_t$?

Comment: Because the set of all $t$ with $g_t \ge f$ is non-empty and bounded from below by $f'(a)$.

Comment: Take $f = -x^2 + 1$ on $[0,1]$. It will intersect with any $g_t$ in 0 and $-t$. For any $t > 0$, $f > g$ on the interval $[0, t]$. So, not sure why this is correct

Comment: Oh, yes. It does not work in this case. I am not really sure under which assumptions on $f$ such a function $g$ does exist...

Answer (score 0):

Consider a convex quadratic coord $h :[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ pinned at $P := (a, -f(a)) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $Q := (b, -f(b)) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, and stretch it vertically until it is below the graph of $-f$. Take $p := b$, and use a bit of algebra to verify that the choice $g := -h$ (obtained by flippling $h$ about the horizontal axis) does the job.

Alternatively, If you're a physicist, think of $f$ as a segment of a heavy chain pinned at $P$ and $Q$, and let it sag under gravity. When it comes to a stand-still, it produces a hyperbolic cosine curve $h$. Now, taking $g := -h$ trivially satisfies the conditions you seek (once again, with $p := b$).

Comment: what if f is concave in $[a,b]$? will it work?

Comment: Yes, of course. Why not ? I assumed nothing more than the assumptions in your question.

Comment: Think about $f(x) = \sqrt{-x^2 + 2x}$ on $[0,2]$, when $p_0 = 0$. Will it work here? if so, I don't understand the method

Comment: Oops! Sorry I read the inequality in your question in the reversed sense. I've update the answer accordingly. The trick is to instead consider $-f$ instead, and then flip the previously proposed $g$ about the horizontal axis.